# What type of cluster management software is Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

In my distributed and Cloud computing book the following are ways to manage a cluster:

1. guest-based manager- cluster manager resides on on a guest OS
2. host-based manager- supervises the guest systems and can restart guest system on another physical machine

3.independent cluster manager- management software is on both host and guest os

4.integrated cluster manager- manager must be designed to distinguish b/w virtualized resources and physical resources.

Which label most aptly fits K8?

Comment: Hi, I suggest reading kubernetes documentation overview [What is Kubernetes?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/).

Answer (score 0):

None. All of those terms are related to Virtual Machines where there are strict borders between host and guest. While technically Kubernetes doesn’t require the use of containers, the overwhelming majority of users use Docker containers as the runtime where those boundaries are fuzzy. There is no guest OS, just some process flags.

Comment: Thanks, here's a follow up question @coderanger . So EC2 instances are VMs and ECS is a set of EC2 instances that behave like docker containers which is usually  managed by K8. How does k8 manage EC2 instances in a docker like fashion when there exists VMs?

Comment: It doesn’t? Those things have nothing to do with each other. Kubernetes is, mostly, a way to organize linux containers and a set of support tools for that. It doesn’t even run containers itself, it just coordinates them.